Is Hadamard gate considered a valid beam splitter when dealing with multiple beam splitters?
I have read that Hadamard gate can be a valid 50:50 beam splitter when dealing with one beam splitter , however when dealing with more than one beam splitter the hadamard gate is no longer valid and we need to use other 50:50 beam splitter like the one with the matrix 1/2–√[1 i i 1] .
From what I have read, it has to do with something related to phase shift in the beam splitter , here what is the explanation says :
"Real beam splitters often introduce phase shifts between the reflected and transmitted beams. The Hadamard gate, however, does not introduce a phase shift, as it only alters the amplitudes without affecting the relative phase between the paths."
So my question is , is hadamard gate no longer a valid beam splitter when dealing with multiple beam splitters ? What does the explaination I quoted mean and why doesn't the hadamard gate introduce a phase shift ?

Cross posted https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/39649/15820

Firstly, a Hadamard gate is an abstract theoretical device, while a beamsplitter is a physical optical component. So, the question whether "a Hadamard gate is a valid beam splitter" does not make sense. Instead, one should ask whether a "beam splitter can be a valid Hadamard gate."
The Hadamard gate is give by a $2\times 2$ matrix
$$ \text{Hadamard gate} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{array} \right] . $$
Can we use a beamsplitter to represent this matrix? Being a physical optical component, we need to remember that light acquire phase shift simply by propagating. So, there is always to possibility to multiply any input or output port by a local phase shift. With such phase shifts incorporated, we can represent a 50:50 beamsplitter by
$$ \text{50:50 beamsplitter} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[\begin{array}{cc} \exp(i\phi_1) & 0 \\ 
0 & \exp(i\phi_2)\end{array} \right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array} \right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc} \exp(i\phi_3) & 0 \\ 
0 & \exp(i\phi_4)\end{array} \right] , $$
where the $\phi$'s represent the phase shifts. When you multiply out all the matrices you can equate the elements of the resulting matrix to those of a Hadamard gate to see if the beamsplitter with the phase shifts can represent a Hadamard gate. Hence, we need to satisfy
$$ \exp(i\phi_1+i\phi_3)=1 , ~~~
  -\exp(i\phi_1+i\phi_4)=1 , ~~~
\exp(i\phi_2+i\phi_3)=1  , ~~~ 
\exp(i\phi_2+i\phi_4)=-1 . $$
We can satisfy these conditions provided that
$$ \phi_1=\phi_2=-\phi_3=\pi-\phi_4 . $$
So, in principle, yes the Hadamard gate can be implemented with a 50:50 beamsplitter, if you can control the phases accurately. For a multi-port, you can now perform the same procedure demonstrated here to see if such a multi-port Hadamard gate can be implemented with multiple beamsplitters if you take all the phase shifts into account.

Why can't Hadamard gate be a physical optical component ? Is it because of practical reasons or because of theoritical reasons ?  Theoritically speaking , can Hadamrd gate be  used in multiple beam splitter system ? My treacher said we can't and the reason was somethin that has to do with the phase . I used ChatGPT and it said someting similar (I quoted part of the asnwer in my OG post)  , could you please explain the phase issue with Hadamard gate and why it is just a theoritcal device and can't be physically implemented ?

@firas It just doesn't make sense. A Hadamard gate is an abstraction. It's like asking why a matrix can't be an optical component.
